# Is there a registry key change that will by-pass the Windows Domain Join Welcome page?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-registry, domain, windows-server-2008

I'm scripting some Windows Server 2008 R2 builds using Power Shell.  Some software needs to be installed after the server has joined the domain.  Since I want to automate everything, I'm looking to by-pass the domain controllers Welcome page using a registry hack script.  I work for a large company and the Active Directory people are unwilling to change group policy.  I figure if it's a registry key I can script the change, install the software, replace the key and reboot as the final step.  Is there a registry key change that will by-pass the Domain Join Welcome page?

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to join the server to the domain automatically?  If not, what Welcome page are you talking about?

Comment: If it is something they applied in the GPO, it is applied every reboot, so changing a key will not work. You will have to get them to exclude your computer from the GPO (this usually requires a new OU to be created and you to add your builds to that OU).

Comment: Harry - Yes I join the domain with a script. The problem is upon the domain join the server reboots and I get to a Welcome/Disclaimer page where I have to physically click "OK" then the script continues the build - using the Runonce registry entry.

Comment: Falcon,  Yes I was afraid of that. GPO - can't script around it.  I was wishfully thinking.  A new OU - it may have to be. Thanks for the replys.

Comment: Does it have to be a registry hack?  Couldn't you add a script to run once that would wait for 15 seconds (or how ever long it takes) and then send a carriage return to the active window?

Answer (score 0):

Embed some AutoIT script code to automatically click whatever buttons you need to.

http://trevorsullivan.net/2012/05/25/powershell-integrate-invocation-of-autoit-scripts/